# Is it possible to access a method decorator's information in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I've designed a RBAC method in a Django project using the following concept:

- Declare an attribute `permission_roles` in the View/Viewset body
- This attribute receives information regarding the user roles that can access each method/action of the view (e.g.: `'create': (RoleChoices.ADMIN)`)

Then I had to think how to inform the frontend about role capabilities.

I've thought of using a new model class `Permission` that stores an array of roles and have an unique name identifier (e.g.: `Permission(action="user_management_list", roles=[1,2,3])`)

In order to populate this model, I've used the autodiscover Django's method + a decorator that goes above my view methods/actions:

```
    @allowed_roles('user_management_list', [RoleChoices.ADMIN])
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now I was thinking of a way to merge both functionalities, simplifying the RBAC custom permission by using the action name + the request user role and query directly to the DB (later I'll use also a cache strategy to reduce DB load).

But the problem is, how could I access the decorator's first param (its the action name)?

Comment: UPDATE - I've decided to move the action name ('user_management_list') to the role attribute defined in the class and decorate the whole class. This way I could access the information directly.